# When I create an object and pass arguments my class's constructors fail

Tags: java, object, constructor

New to programming, but constructors seem like a straight forward concept. Just can't figure out why when I create an object and pass arguments in my test class they fail to initialize the Polygon Class's fields.

```
public class Polygon{

    private int numSides;
    private double sideLength, xCoord, yCoord, apothem, perimeter;


    public Polygon(){
        this.numSides = 4;
        this.sideLength = 10.0;
        this.xCoord = 0.0;
        this.yCoord = 0.0;
        this.apothem = 5.0;
        this.perimeter = 20.0;
    }

    public Polygon(int numSides, double sideLength, double xCoord, double yCoord, double apothem, double perimeter){
        this.numSides = numSides;
        this.sideLength = sideLength;
        this.xCoord = xCoord;
        this.yCoord = yCoord;
        this.apothem = apothem;
        this.perimeter = perimeter;
    }

    public static double getArea(double apothem, double perimeter) {
        double area = .5 * apothem * perimeter;
        return area;
    }

    public static String toString(int numSides, double sideLength, double xCoord, double yCoord, double apothem){
        String results = String.format("toString() results: (numSides=%d, sideLength=%.1f%n, xCoord=%.1f%n, yCoord=%.1f%n, apothem=%.1f%n)", numSides, sideLength, xCoord, yCoord, apothem);
        return results;
    }
}
```

And the test class

```
public class TestPolygon {

    public static void main(String[] args){  

        Polygon testPoly = new Polygon(4, 10.0, 0.0, 0.0, 5.0, 20.0);
        String results = testPoly.toString();
        System.out.println(results);
        double area = testPoly.getArea();
        System.out.printf("getArea() results: %.1f%n", area);   

    } // End main method

}
```

Comment: Now explain what you expect to happen and what actually happens.

Comment: public static String toString  is not overriding toString

Comment: I expect my creating an object in my test class and passing all the arguments in my constructor that I will no longer have to pass arguments when using that object to call methods in the polygon class. What is happening is that none of fields in the constructor are initialized with the arguments I passed.

Comment: @smus87: you can't say that at all as your testing is faulty as the answers below explain. In other words you're chasing the wrong horse: the problem is not the constructor at all, but how your printing things out. Again, I'm surprised that the code even compiled.

Comment: Yes, I was too busy looking at the constructor for the error I didnt consider the rest of the code, thanks for the help everyone.

Answer (score 2):

You're calling `Polygon.toString()` but you've implemented `Polygon.toString(int, double, double, double, double)`

Get rid of the parameters in your `toString()` (overriding `Object.toString()` then) and it will work fine. Also, it can't be `static`

Comment: Just like you said it worked fine. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Your code shouldn't even compile since you're calling `getArea(...)` without its parameters.

But having said that, getArea shouldn't require parameters in the first place and definitely shouldn't be static.

Also, `toString()` shouldn't be static and should take no parameters, and should have an `@Override` annotation above it.